# Who's "Her' in Joseph Addison's Cato's Soliloquy?

Tags: meaning

This is a Soliloquy from Joseph Addison's [Cato](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cato,_a_Tragedy), also known as [Edgar Allan Poe’s Cryptographic Challenge](http://www.guerrillaexplorer.com/mysteries-of-history/the-edgar-allan-poe-code/), the whole play [could be found here.](http://www.constitution.org/addison/cato_play.htm)

> The soul, secured in her existence, smiles
>   at the drawn dagger, and defies its point.
>   The stars shall fade away, the sun himself
>   grow dim with age, and nature sink in years;
>   But thou shalt flourish in immortal youth,
>   unhurt amid the war of elements,
>   The wreck of matter, and the crash of worlds!

My question is very simple ,who is **Her**? What's her name, and what's her story?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several concepts that are traditionally personified as feminine in English use.

This was particularly important earlier in English when it was common to use *his* where we would now use *its*, as for these cases we would use *her*.

While that is long ago (back to the very beginnings of Early Modern English), the convention of using the feminine for certain cases remains to the current day, though in the last century it began to become less popular.

Those cases where we use the feminine include ships, assemblages of people (cities, countries, churches), and the soul.

And hence, since the previous noun is indeed *soul*, we would expect this to be the case here.

See the mid-15th century "How Man's flesh complained to God against Christ." for an early example.

> [The soul has been addressed a few verses back when we come to…]
>
> She is ashamed, now she is wys;
>
> Sche lyued in vowtrye so many a day.
>
> She haþ chosen þe loue most o prys,
>
> And cast þe fals[e] loue away.'
>
> God seiþ: 'man, y made þe of nouȝt,
>
> And kyd þat y loued þe dere,
>
> And soule of resoun in þe wrouȝt,
>
> ffayre and wys, angels pere.
>
> Þou hast defouled þe ymage þat y wrouȝt,
>
> In seruage to fendis and fendis fere.
>
> She folwed þy wille in dede and þouȝt,
>
> In alle place, fer and nere.

Earlier still, *soul* is only found with a feminine pronoun in Old English.

Coming through to more modern times, we have this from a 1692 sermon by John Cotton:

> O when wilt thou come unto me, sais the Soul. She desires to dwell in the house of the Lord, & there to behond his beauty.

The example in the question brings us up to the 19th Century.

It began to become less common in the 20th, because analysis of the use of gendered pronouns for non-gendered subjects became politically questionable.

(I'm leaving aside various mystical views that held that the soul actually **was** feminine; while they may have influenced the choice of pronoun, the choice of pronoun should not generally be taken as suggesting the soul is female, any more than a ship or a country is).

Answer (score 1):

The soul is being referred to by the feminine her.

There is no other woman or entity being referred to there. Rather the soul is being anthropomorphized (assuming you don't believe souls to be already).

Granted, within a greater context there could be a woman specifically being referred to as "The soul" but that would require either a preceding (or at least a later callback) introduction or the usage of "The Soul" as a proper noun.

Comment: Question updated. The whole play is now added.

Answer (score 0):

I am from Italy originally so most probably I don't have the knowledge to properly answer this question... but sometimes ago I asked a similar question to a colleague of mine who used the pronoun "She" when talking about a Server... a Pc Server and to the operating System on it. This colleague told me that because of the "instability" of the object sometimes and especially in the past people were used to refer to all the instable objects even metaphysic "objects" using feminine pronouns.. which of course it sounds to be not polite and awkward today on regard of women but this is what he told me...

Comment: Your colleague's problems with women, aside, he was plain wrong. Ships, nations, armies, churches and cities are generally considered to be strong things, as indeed was the soul which was conceived of as indestructible and eternal in the metaphysics that most impacted upon English.

Comment: Ya I totally agree with you... most probably it was just a kind of bad & gross superstition of course coming from the past. But thank you for the answer and clarification